# System Freezes Briefly when changing from one keyboard to another

Tags: keyboard, xorg

I have a laptop with US keyboard and an external keyboard with portuguese brazil layout. If I press any button in one keyboard then I press in the other one, the system freezes briefly. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the ScrollLock key on the layout file.

In my case, it is found at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br`.

Comment the line: `modifier_map Mod3 { Scroll_Lock };`

No more delays!